# Observe sms sending app in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

Is there a way to read outgoing sms from the emulator?

In the logcat I see this message:

```
D/SmsStorageMonitor(  738): SMS send size=0 time=1327423357467
```

Is there a way to get the receiver and the content?

The outgoing sms seems not to be saved in the emulator. That means that the messenger app shows me no sms.

Comment: Curious if there is a way to do this outside of rewriting parts of the SDK. There doesn't seem to be any way, that I can find at least, to get the sms message out from behind the virtual router.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes just create one service in your app and observe all outgoing sms just refer below code.

```
public class SMSObserver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    static final String ACTION ="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT";

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    { 
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) 
        {
                 //your action code here
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me where i can find this action, i mean if i want a wanted action, how can i confirm whether the system had it. I usually find it in `platform/android**/data`, but i don't find this action.

Comment: visit this link http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/provider/Telephony.java

Comment: i didn't find the intent defined in `Telephony`class.

Comment: Firstly test above code,for me it's work fine,is it worked for you?

Comment: I just want to find a place where can find all the system intent actions :)

Comment: @dreamtale : see this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094109/android-how-to-i-get-a-list-of-all-available-intent-filters

Answer (score 1):

If you're using your local database to store the outgoing messages while sending from your application, it is possible.

Comment: Sorry no the app seems to delete that entries. The database is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try to observe the content resolver like following code:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
contentResolver.registerContentObserver("content://sms", true, yourObserver);
```