# Receive broadcast when send an sms

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

How to receive broadcast when a user sends SMS from his Android phone? I am creating an application which is taking track of sent SMS and calls. I am done with the calls part, please help me with the SMS. Note that sms are sent by the phone not any application.

----------//solution-----------

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(VIEW_RESOURCE_ID);

            SendSmsObserver smsObeserver = (new SendSmsObserver(new Handler()));
            ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
            contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"),true, smsObeserver);
        }


    public class SendSmsObserver extends ContentObserver {

            public SendSmsObserver(Handler handler) {
                super(handler);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                super.onChange(selfChange);
                // save the message to the SD card here

                 Log.d("sent sms", "one text send");

            }
        }
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550178/intercepting-outgoing-sms/7790755#7790755

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808577/android-listen-outgoing-sms-or-sent-box

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990558/android-broadcast-receiver-for-sent-sms-messages

Comment: is there any problem in my code if yes plz let me know

Comment: see this question [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991339/observe-sms-sending-app-in-emulator/9582426#9582426

Comment: there is an difference between both i was asking for phone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991339/observe-sms-sending-app-in-emulator/9582426#9582426 was asked for emulator @Girish bhutia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(VIEW_RESOURCE_ID);

                SendSmsObserver smsObeserver = (new SendSmsObserver(new Handler()));
                ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
                contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"),true, smsObeserver);
            }


        public class SendSmsObserver extends ContentObserver {

                public SendSmsObserver(Handler handler) {
                    super(handler);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                    super.onChange(selfChange);
                    // save the message to the SD card here

                     Log.d("sent sms", "one text send");

                }
            }
```

Comment: what about if i want to track the sms sent but for which the sms that was delivered by the app instead of the built-in function?

Comment: The SMS sending application is your application or any third party application ?

Comment: I don't know why but it logs each sms sent event 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

You could build on  [CallLog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html). The CallLog provider contains information about placed and received calls.

The Following code can work

```
Cursor c = null; try {
    c = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            int duration = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
            // do something with duration
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    } } finally {
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    } }
```

--------------------------ADDED NEW SOLUTION------------------------

Have a look at:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9bc7d7ba0229a1d2

and :
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=914

Basically, you can do it by registering a content observer on the SMS
message store.Try
this:

```
  ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"),true, smsObeserver);
```

Comment: with calls i have done but the only problem is in getting sent sms broadcast

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808577/android-listen-outgoing-sms-or-sent-box

Comment: yes i have checked and i am not getting logs please take a look at my code

Comment: i see you have done the content observer part... see the two new link i have added...it may help you out

Comment: this line was causing problem madcontentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://
sms/out"),true, myObserver);