# Android dev: How I can find the list of all avaiable intent-filter actions for a receiver?

Tags: android, action, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I'd like to know how you can find a specific "action" to make your own "BroadcastReceivers" from your manifest file.

There is a list of the action that I can add on "intent-filter" for my BroadcastReceiver?

For example:

```
   <receiver android:name=".Receiver_01_OnSettingChange">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Where I can find the list of the others action related to the other setting states?

Many thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html there is a list of actions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PackageExplorer lists all intent-filters defined in apps in your device.More information can be had from this link

[Android -- How to get a list of all available intent filters ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094109/android-how-to-i-get-a-list-of-all-available-intent-filters)

Using java method , you can read androidmanifest xml to binary format.Then you can write to a text file.The below link talka about that.

[How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Many thanks, but I can get the list of intents to a text file?