# How to get all intent filters for application (with root)

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on a system application and I need to know programmatically what intents an application is capable of handling. I have seen other questions related to this, but none of them seem to have an answer but also do not seem to be concerned with system privileges.

PackageManager only seems to provide methods to query activities for a given intent. I can not find a way to get intents for a given activity.

For example, if I have an activity which has intent filters defined as such:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And I know the activities class name and package name, I would like to find out from the package manager (or any other source) what intents it can handle (in this case, `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `USER_PRESENT`).

Comment: Just a shoot in the dark - if you have root privilages, you could probably get manifest files from installed apps and parse them (apk files are just zip files). If you are still interested I could try to check if this idea works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. I don't think it's possible to find out the intents that an app can handle. Some standard activity actions and broadcast actions are listed at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html. If you are writing your own app that's having it's own intent filters, then i don't think other apps will know what intents your app can handle because there is no way to publish them or announce them to the world, i believe.

But what is possible is that you can make a call for a particular intent and if that returns null, then you know for sure that there are no apps on the device that can handle that particular intent.

HTH.

Comment: I had just found some information on this when I saw your answer. You are correct, at the moment there does not seem to be any way to do this. For known android intents you can query all intents one at a time for all applications, but this is a lot of work for something so simple.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for confirming my believes. There are not very many standard i.e known actions. So, looping around them is not an issue. Typically, any app or library will provide documentation if their intent is to allow other apps to use their components. This is esp. true of 3rd party SDKS. May be, that's the reason why there does not exist a "query" mode like the one you wish for.

Answer (score 2):

So after just asking this question, I found this wonderful answer here:

[Android — How to I get a list of all available intent filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4746835/1306452)

Which leads to this [5 year old issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3217)

So it doesn't seem like there is any way to do what I want to do at the moment. If it becomes available, I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a decompiler, such as "DexDump" (available on GooglePlay), and retrieve the "AndroidManifest.xml" of the application you want to know about.