# How to check if an intent can be handled by an Android service?

Tags: android, android-intent

My android device exposes an `Intent` I can use to control some of its functionalities. Unfortunately, this is not the only device I use and I need to be able to tell if it is this one or some other.
The only way I know how I could tell the difference is by checking if the exposed `Intent` is there or not.
Of course, there are tonnes of questions about checking if an `Activity` exists which could handle a specific `Intent`, but in this case, there's no `Activity` behind it - the `resolveActivity()` call returns `null` even though the `Intent` is handled fine.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27918003/487605) answer and I can see the intent on the list, but I cannot find a way to get this list programatically inside my app or service.

Answer (score 1):

PackageManager exposes [resolveService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#resolveService(android.content.Intent,%20int)), exactly for this purpose:

> *abstract ResolveInfo resolveService (Intent intent, int flags)*
>
> Determine the best service to handle for a given Intent.