# How to get list of activities with specific intent action

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, action

How i can get list of activities for any intent action?

for example we have intent with action SEND or intent with action SEND_MULTIPLE. How i can get list of packages for intents with this action and some extras,to it work in android 11? Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to implement?

Comment: If you can plug your device into your development machine, you can `adb.exe shell dumpsys package r` for a list of actions and apps.  Works with emulator as well.  From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094109/android-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-available-intent-filters.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [`queryIntentActivities`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)) from the `PackageManager`:

> Retrieve all activities that can be performed for the given intent.

For example for the SEND action, you would do the following:

```
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, null);
    List<ResolveInfo> result = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```