# Get all the activities/packagename/apps name which are displayed in chooser intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, payment-gateway, intentfilter

I want to get list of all the activities that can handle UPI intent.
OR
I want to get list of all activities that are displayed in Chooser intent for a upi intent.

e.g google pay, amazon pay, paytm etc

[image: wallet apps image]

```
    void payUsingUpi() {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay").buildUpon().build();
        
        Intent upiPayIntent = new Intent();
        upiPayIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        upiPayIntent.setData(uri);

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");
        
        // check if intent resolves
        if (chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            activityLauncherForUpiPayements.launch(chooser);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No UPI app found, please install one to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityLauncherForUpiPayements = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        // Toast.makeText(WalletActivity.this, "returned from activty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (result.getData() != null) {
                String trxt = result.getData().getStringExtra("response");
                //Log.d("UPI", "onActivityResult: " + trxt);
                ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                dataList.add(trxt);
                upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList);
            } else {
                //Log.d("UPI", "onActivityResult: " + "Return data is null");
                ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                dataList.add("nothing");
                upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList);
            }
        } else {
            //Log.d("UPI", "onActivityResult: " + "Return data is null"); //when user simply back without payment
            ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
            dataList.add("nothing");
            upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList);
        }
    });
```

I have tried below snippet provided in other [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069769/how-to-get-list-of-activities-with-specific-intent-action)

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> result = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(chooser, 0);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : result) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

it gave output like below:

> android
> android.system.ui.chooser

but I want to get all activities or package name or app name that were displayed in chooser pop-up.

Comment: Start by deleting `Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");`. Then, call `queryIntentActivities()` on an instance of `PackageManager`, passing in `upiPayIntent`. You will need to [add a `<queries>` element to your manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring) that matches your `Intent` structure.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added query tag to manifest
    <queries><intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="upi" />
        </intent></queries>

commented/deleted the line you told,

        List<ResolveInfo> result = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(upiPayIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : result) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Output: in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping


all other UPI apps are not in the output. TYSM.

Comment: I would use something other than `Toast`, such as Logcat. You might need to add the `pay` path segment to your `<queries>` configuration.

Comment: Excellent, it worked. Added android:host="pay" to data tag inside queries tag.

Complete query tag is here.

<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="upi" android:host="pay"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>

thanks a lot.
PS: I'm one of the readers of your books. 

Comment: You might want to post an answer to your own question with your worked-out solution. I am glad that you got it going, and I hope that you found the books to be useful!

Comment: Of course I will write complete answer with explanation little later(busy right now). Every android developer would find your books to be useful. 

Comment: @CodingDevil write your own solutions as an complete answer.