# How can I access all intents for an application? I want to extract the intentions of the selected app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest, feature-extraction

the following code writes only the main intention (android.intent.action.MAIN) in JSON

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setPackage(applicationInfo.packageName);
List<ResolveInfo> intentList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
                
JSONArray intentsArray = new JSONArray();
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : intentList) {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(newComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));

    String action = intent.getAction();
    intentsArray.put(action);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How to get a list of all available intent filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094109/android-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-available-intent-filters)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.